# Which clients support only TLSv1.1 but not TLSv1.2?

Tags: tls

I phrased the question originally as **Is there any point in supporting TLSv1.1 on the server side?**

The recommended current setup if you don't have full control over your clients is to support TLSv1.0, TLSv1.1, and TLSv1.2 (this is recommended by the Intermediate Profile of the Mozilla SSL Configuration Generator for example).

One thing I noticed recently when I checked yet another server with Qualys' SSL Server Test was that all listed reference clients will use either TLSv1.0 or TLSv1.2.  There is also a "[TLS/SSL support history of web browsers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Web_browsers)" on Wikipedia which suggests the same apart from some older intermediate versions.

There is currently not much harm in supporting TLSv1.1 but I like to be as strict as possible and don't see the point in supporting an older TLS version which nobody uses anyway and which might cause trouble in the future.

So my question:  Which clients apart from older browsers are out there which support TLSv1.1 but not TLSv1.2?  I'm especially interested in TLS libraries/wrapper or odd combinations of such clients and OpenSSL versions which were shipped by major Linux distributions and still supported by the vendor.  There might also be some Java versions between 7u25 and 8u31 (the versions listed by Qualys) for which this applies.

This isn't limited to HTTPS clients but for example mail clients (SMTP, IMAP, …) as well.

Comment: this is impossible to answer unless you dramatically narrow the area. This question is not broad, is **BROAD**.

Comment: I don't think it is really impossible to answer. I'll try to narrow it down further by restricting it to "common" clients (whatever that is) but I myself after some shallow research wasn't able to find any samples of clients for which the criteria applies. So I think the answers should be rather short even though the question space is rather broad.